# A rem is not a rem?

Tags: android, css, android-4.1-jelly-bean

I've got strange result on an Android device while trying to use rem unit for adaptive HTML page. When opening [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rjndvsmz/) on any device, I expect to see "640" in the alert message. It works well on all my devices except of a tablet pc where it shows 832. Why?

html:

```
<div id="div"></div>
```

css:

```
html {
  font-size: 640px;
}
#div {
  width: 1rem;
}
```

js:

```
$(window).load(alert($('#div').width()))
```

Device info:

- Prestigio MultiPad PMP5580C
- Android 4.1.1
- Built-in Browser app
- Screen resolution: 1024x768

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the "Text scaling" browser feature. It was set to 130%.

[image: Text scaling in Android browser]